# UpdateCursor not calculating the date

Tags: arcpy, cursor, date

My UpdateCursor isn't working in arcpy.  Here's my code:

```
urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(firstDatabase+ os.sep + "Temp")
for urow in urows:
    urow.Import_Date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    urow.File_Name = str(table)
    urows.updateRow(urow)
```

It will always error out on the Import_Date field saying "error executing function".

The Import_Date is a 'date' field.

Any ideas?

Here is a screen shot of the loop when I add "arcpy.AddMessage(urow)" in the code and # out the other stuff.
[image]

Comment: What format is the Import_Date field?

Comment: If you comment out the urow.Import_Date line, are you able to perform the urow.File_Name line without an error?

Comment: It's a date field.

Comment: See [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Converting_string_or_numeric_time_values_into_date_format/005z00000028000000/)

Comment: It still errors out when I # out the line, but now it goes one line further down?

Comment: what does print urow, type(urow) say (put just after your for clause)?

Comment: See above, Clay.

Comment: have you tried `datetime.datetime.today()`?

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't work.

Comment: It works if the field is a text, but it won't work with a date field....

Comment: you have imported the time library haven't you?

Comment: Does `time.strftime` work by itself? I couldn't reproduce this at all in 10.2.1 (no errors), and I even tried several different time formats.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the dot field name notation that you are using, use the setValue/getValue notation instead.  I just tried something like the following on a date field and it works fine:

```
urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(os.path.join(firstDatabase, "Temp"))
for urow in urows:
    urow.setValue("Import_Date", time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    urow.setValue("File_Name", str(table))
    urows.updateRow(urow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try usin arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) . Then instead of using the dot field name notation, use the index e.g. row[0]. I recommend using a with statement and cursor.Make sure to commit by calling .updateRow more info here (http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000)

Assuming you have 10.x, I am not sure if da.UpdateCursor existed in 9.x

Comment: The da cursors weren't available until 10.1